# java 8 map with multiple keys to same value

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, key

I am looking for some handy way of creation of following map. I have an objects which contain such field (examples)

```
Object1: Set<String> supportedKeys = {A, B, C};
Object2: Set<String> supportedKeys = {D};
```

And I want to have a map like this:

```
{A, Object1} {B, Object1} {C, Object1} {D, Object2}
```

I did it like this

```
object1.supportedKeys.forEach(k->map.put(k, object1))
object2.supportedKeys.forEach(k->map.put(k, object2))
```

But I feel like there,s more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: What do you think is not efficient? If you're going to look up by `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, then this is just about it.

Comment: What if both `Set`s contain same `String`?  `Object2` should be the value then?

Comment: @michalk not allowed, if it happens, there's a bug in code. This is exceptional scenario

Answer (score 0):

Given a `List` (or any `Collection`) of your objects, you can `Stream` over the elements, use `flatMap` to generate pairs of keys and values and collect to a `Map`.

This can be done in a single statement, regardless of the number of your objects.

```
List.of(object1,object2)
    .stream()
    .flatMap(o -> o.supportedKeys
                   .stream()
                   .map(k -> new SimpleEntry<>(k,o)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: `more efficient` ?

Comment: Why not `Stream.of` directly instead of creating useless `List`?

Comment: @Rono Well, it seems cleaner than practically writing the same statement twice (or multiple times if there are more than 2 objects to process).

Comment: @michalk you are correct for the OP's example, but I was assuming a more general input that already comes in some Collection.